# angular viewChild for dynamic elements inside ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

My template has something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of array">
    <div #div></div>
</div>
```

is there a way for me to name each div differently using the #? And if so, how can I access them later in my TS file?

by the way, what are these # called? I cant search for them since I have now idea what these are (I just know what they're used for)

Comment: Pity, but it's impossible to name these references dynamically, so you can't do something like `#div{{i}}`.

Comment: They are called template reference variables - https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you need to name them dynamically and what's your final goal?

Comment: these divs will be filled with Konva images after an image submit, but I need to get their size whenever I resize my window (which I did using window:resize), create them or do some other stuff like minimizing/maximizing the window, which I beieve can be done through events and having references to them using viewChild

Answer (score 74, accepted):

TL;DR Use `ViewChildren` instead of `ViewChild`

As @Commerical Suicide mentioned you cannot set the references dynamically.

The `#div` is called [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars).

You can access your *divs* via [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) in you `*.ts` file.

Sample: `@ViewChildren('div') divs: QueryList<ElementRef>`

Then you can call multiple methods on your new `QueryList`, like `forEach` or  `find`.

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternative way to catch and handle dynamic elements inside the loop by events.

```
<div *ngFor="let name of names">
  <input #boofoo type="text" (click)="onClick($event, name)" />
  <button (click)="boofoo.click()">Change text</button>
</div>
```

See example
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7ieq5r?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a child component that will have its logic

Exemple :

**menu-horizontal.component.html**

```html
<nav id='site-header__nav__desktop'>
    <template-menu-item *ngFor="let link of navLinks" [navItem]="link">
    </template-menu-item>
</nav>
```

**menu-item.component.html**

```html
<div>
    <a class="nav-link" #parent routerLink="/test" (click)="toggle()">
        {{ navItem.text }}
    </a>
    <ul #children class="children-menu" *ngIf="navItem.children">
        <li *ngFor="let child of navItem.children">
            <a [href]="child.link">
                {{child.text}}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In this example the action of toggle targets the child of the menu item, otherwise it will have selected the first children found